# How to fix NuGet package access error on OSX using VScode?

Tags: .net, macos, visual-studio-code, nuget

I'm trying to get our .net project set up locally on a Mac using VS Code.

I have been running into build issues and was finally able to narrow it down to not having access to our private Azure repo. We have a few packages that our project uses stored in there.

Initially the issue was that it just couldn't find them. The fix was to create a nuget.config file and add the  to that.

But I was still running into access errors.

It turns out my account wasn't granted access to azure so got that taken care of. I can now access the package file (JSON) directly in the browser no problem, but an still running into this error when building the project:

> error NU1301: Unable to load the service index for source

What I've looked into:

- double check the account I'm logged into VSCode with is the same account I can log into Azure with. This supposedly should "just work".
- created a PAT in azure and added to my nuget.config file as such:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
      <clear /> <!-- (optional) this is for clear sources like default Offline repo -->
      <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
      <add key="[myKey]" value="https://url..." protocolVersion="3" />
  </packageSources>
  <packageSourceCredentials>
    <MyPrivateFeed>
      <add key="Username" value="[myUsernameForThePAT]" />
      <add key="ClearTextPassword" value="[myPAT]" />
    </MyPrivateFeed>
  </packageSourceCredentials>
</configuration>
```

- Deleted the nuget cache under `.local/share/nuget`
- googled 'nuget' issues extensively and learned that Mac has a rough go at it as VSCode doesn't get any of the nuget management tools Visual Studio gets and the CLI tool for nuget is an .exe file.

And now I am out of ideas. Any suggestions as to what to look into next appreciated!